# How to copy from S3 production to S3 development using Python with different roles?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy files from S3 Production(where i have only read access) to S3 development (i have write access). The change which i face is switching the roles. 
While coping i need use prod role and while writing i need to use developer role.

I am trying with below code:

```
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='prod_role')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

copy_source = {
      'Bucket': 'prod_bucket',
      'Key': 'file.txt'
    }

bucket = s3.Bucket('dev_bucket')
bucket.copy(copy_source, 'file.txt')
```

I need to know how to switch the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to move data between buckets in Amazon S3 is to use the `resource.copy()` or `client.copy_object()` command. This allows the two buckets to directly communicate (even between different regions), without the need to download/upload the objects themselves.

However, the credentials used to call the command require **both read permission from the source and write permission to the destination**. It is not possible to provide two different sets of credentials for this copy.

Therefore, you should **pick ONE set of credentials** and ensure it has the appropriate permissions. This means either:

- Give the Prod credentials permission to write to the destination, or
- Give the non-Prod credentials permission to read from the Prod bucket

This can be done either by creating a **Bucket Policy**, or by assigning permissions directly to the **IAM Role/User** being used.

If this is a regular task that needs to happen, you could consider automatically copying the files by using an **Amazon S3 event on the source bucket to trigger a Lambda function** that copies the object to the non-Prod destination immediately. This avoids the need to copy files in a batch at some later time.